# 'data' has class 'character' and length 537600. 'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename

Tags: r, xgboost, forecasting, forecast

I am trying out the following code for XGboost model:

```
model_function <- function(data, outcome_col = 2) {

  # xgboost cannot handle missing outcomes data.
  data <- data[!is.na(data[, outcome_col]), ]

  indices <- 1:nrow(data)

  set.seed(224)
  train_indices <- sample(1:nrow(data), ceiling(nrow(data) * .8), replace = FALSE)
  test_indices <- indices[!(indices %in% train_indices)]
  # data_train[] <- lapply(data_train, as.numeric)
  # 
  # data_train[] <- as.numeric(levels(data_train))[data_train]
  # # xgb.DMatrix(data=data.matrix(datrain))

  data_train <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(data[train_indices,
                                                           -(outcome_col), drop = FALSE]),
                                     label = as.matrix(data[train_indices,
                                                            outcome_col, drop = FALSE]))

  data_test <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(data[test_indices,
                                                          -(outcome_col), drop = FALSE]),
                                    label = as.matrix(data[test_indices,
                                                           outcome_col, drop = FALSE]))

  params <- list("objective" = "reg:linear")
  watchlist <- list(train = data_train, test = data_test)

  set.seed(224)
  model <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = data_train, params = params,
                              max.depth = 8, nthread = 2, nrounds = 30,
                              metrics = "rmse", verbose = 0,
                              early_stopping_rounds = 5,
                              watchlist = watchlist)

  return(model)
}
```

str(data)

```
data.frame':    4000 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Date   : chr  "2012-04-01" "2012-04-02" "2012-04-03" "2012-04-04" ...
 $ Voltage: num  3.3 3.43 3.44 3.45 3.46 ...
 $ Current: num  0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ static : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ index  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ year   : num  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
```

Can anyone lease explain me why i am getting the error

'data' has class 'character' and length 537600.   'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename.

and please explain me why i am getting the error and suggest any changes in the code please!!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's due to the column, Date. Try converting it into some numeric format and run the function.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram I used as.numeric function yet it does not get converted to numeric can u suggest me any other way to do the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: Considering "1899-12-30" as the origin (like in excel), the dates can be converted into numeric by: as.numeric(as.Date(data$Date)-as.Date(0, origin="1899-12-30"))